# Java stream Collection Map

Tags: java, stream, maps

I have a map which has as key string, and as a value a list of objects `Names`. In this map, I saved information some years about a `Names`. Each object of the `` class has a name, gender and rank atributes.

```
Map <String, ArrayList<Names>> myMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
List<Names> filterList = myMap.filter((k, v) -> v.name == name).collect(Collectors.toList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input map is like this:

```java
Map<String, List<BabyName>> inputMap;
```

The list of `BabyName` should be retrieved using `flatMap` and `filter` operations of Stream API:

```
List<BabyName> result = inputMap.values() // Collection<List<BabyName>>
        .stream() // Stream<List<BabyName>>
        .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<BabyName>
        .filter(bn -> bn.getRank() == 3) // filtered Stream<BabyName>
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it, not sure if I am being helpful here. I'm fairly new to Java and programming in general.

```
//Method that takes an ArrayList, filter the list, and returns a new ArrayList
public static ArrayList<BabyName> filterArrayList(ArrayList<BabyName> inputList, int filter) {
        ArrayList<BabyName> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BabyName babyName: inputList) {
            if (babyName.getRank() == filter)
                returnList.add(babyName);
        } return returnList;
    }
```

This block of code basically iterates the TreeMap, and calls the above method. The ArrayList returned by the above method gets added to a new ArrayList `mFilteredList`.

```
ArrayList<BabyName> mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Iterator<ArrayList<BabyName>> iterator = myMap.values().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            ArrayList<BabyName> nameList = iterator.next();
            mFilteredList.addAll(filterArrayList(nameList, 2));
        }
```